# SQOL Query AND Title is failed to pull records

Tags: soql, files

I am using Conga and I am trying to pull files that contain SPE in their tile

This query will find the file records successfully
SELECT ContentDocument.id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '0WO6F000001UbmC' 
 but I want to just find the record that has SPE in the title

So I have added 
AND Title LIKE '%SPE%'

But I am getting no results with that "AND Title LIKE '%SPE%'
"

See record [image: FROM UI]

This is the console with no results when AND is added 
[image: dev console]

Where am I going wrong with the AND Title LIKE '%SPE%'

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

ContentDocumentLink object doesn't have title field.

But I get what you are trying to do:

try this, works for me

```
select id,contentDocumentId,contentDocument.title from contentdocumentlink 
where LinkedEntityId = 'Your own record id ' and  contentDocument.title like '%SPE%'
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocumentLink.htm) does not have a field `Title`. You'd need to query through the relationship to `ContentDocument`:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '0WO6F000001UbmC' AND ContentDocument.Title LIKE '%SPE%'
```

Your query should fail to execute as written.